# Populate word table using python-docx

Tags: python, ms-word, jinja2, python-docx

I have a table to populate [table to populate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HFPq.png), I am quite new to python-docx. I have tried to populate it using render but it's only giving as output one server:

```
for i in serverJson:
        doc.render(i)
```

where serverJson is the list of servers entered by the user. for e.g:

```
    for i in appserver: 
        server_1={"component":"Tomcat","comp_version":"7","server":i,
                                         "app_port":"5000","db_sid":" ","db_port":"200"}
    
        server_2={"component":"Apache","comp_version": "2.4","server":i,
                                    "app_port":" ","db_sid":" ","db_port":"200"}
        serverJson.append(server_1)
        serverJson.append(server_2)
```

My question is how do i populate the table shown in the link with the number of servers entered by user?

Comment: It looks like you are using python-docx-template (`docxtpl`), not `python-docx` directly. Have you checked out the documentation for that here: https://docxtpl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/? Also, it looks like `docxtpl` uses `Jinja`, so that Jinja syntax would be what is used for things like looping.

Comment: Yes sorry, definitely python-docx-template. I have checked the documentation. But i am unable to implement it. I mean to use the for loop, it has to be in the form of a dictionnary. I have put the servers entered by the user in this format as seen above, but i don't know what to do next.

Comment: The changes to implement the looping will be changes to the template, not to the Python code that (just) tells `docxtpl` to _render_ the template. So you'd be looking to add something like the `{% for item in navigation %}` "template-loop" that appears in the code block of this Jinja documentation page:   https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#synopsis. I expect that means adding something like `{% for server in serverJson %}` into the Word document that serves as the "template" for this code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So, what you are actually doing with this block of code:

```
for i in serverJson:
    doc.render(i)
```

Is to render the same doc multiple times, but only using the **single** variables you provided. Instead, you need to provide a jinja `for` statement inside the block itself, to allow it to dynamically create rows and columns. You will have to operate on both your `docx` file and on the Python code. Firstly, create a table and make your `docx` file look like:

[image]

Above, we are using some jinja2 `for loops` to achieve the following:

- Generate as many columns in the headers as we need
- Generate as many rows as the servers in the list
- Generate as many columns containing the data of the server in question

In order to populate the above template with the correct context, take a look at the below code:

```
from docxtpl import DocxTemplate
import os,sys

#Just change these according to your needs
inputFileName = "i.docx"
outputFileName = "o.docx"

#This is done to obtain the absolute paths to the input and output documents,
#because it is more reliable than using the relative path
basedir = os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])
path = os.path.join(basedir, "", inputFileName)
outpath = os.path.join(basedir, "", outputFileName)

template = DocxTemplate(path)

#Specify all your headers in the headers column
context = {
'headers' : ['Component', 'Component Version', 'Server FQDN', 'Application port', 'DB SID', 'DB Port', 'Infos'],
'servers': []
}

#Fictious appserver list
appserver = ['a','b']

#Add data to servers 1 and 2 using a list and not a dict, remember to add
#an empty string for the Infos, as well, otherwise the border won't be drawn
for i in appserver: 
    server_1= ["Tomcat",7,i,5000," ",200,""]
    server_2= ["Apache",2.4,i," "," ",200,""]
    context['servers'].append(server_1)
    context['servers'].append(server_2)

template.render(context)
template.save(outpath)
```

The above, will produce `o.docx` which will look like:

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot!! I now understand Jinja a bit better too. My question now is that how do you insert the table on a single page without it breaking. Because since it is the bottom of the page, the header is showing at the bottom and the contents, on a new page. are there any particular function in Jinja that will help? I looked at the documentation, i cannot find anything.

Comment: No problem Tarini, I am glad I could help you! :) Regarding the problem that you mentioned, maybe you could easily solve it by inserting a [page-break](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/insert-a-page-break-in-word-eb0e569c-8e3f-4db4-9b13-7bfe1cabdbd7) before the table itself, in word?

Comment: yees!! Not quite used to word too :p thank you very much! I know it's a lot in a day, but i posted another question: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66605302/addtional-rows-showing-in-doc-table-using-jinja 
I know only one expert in jinja here being you. Can you please help? :/

Comment: You're welcome! I have answered you there too. I have seen that you've not only copy-pasted the code but reworked it quite significantly. That's great, way to go for your personal improvement. Hopefully this will enable you to help somebody else in the future!

Comment: Thank you very much! I am learning bit by bit and people like you make learning easier.