# Text not showing in word when using Jinja

Tags: python, jinja2

I am trying to place the servers entered by user and append it to a table in word.

This is the jinja code I have implemented in my word template table:

[image: Jinja Table].

I have run my code, where I created a `defaultdic`, so that each server entered by user, the values are appended to the same key:

```py
serverDic = defaultdict(list)
doc = DocxTemplate("documentation_template.docx")
for i in appserver:
    server_1 = {
        "component":"Tomcat",
        "comp_version":"7",
        "server":i,
        "app_port":"5000",
        "db_sid":" ",
        "db_port":"2436"
    }
    for key, value in server_1.items():
        serverDic[key].append(value)

doc.render(serverDic)
```

`serverDic` output:

[image: serverDic output].

But I am getting as output:

[image: output table].

Only the `db_port` is being written to the `doc`. As for the rest, the values are not showing. I don't know where the issue is.

---

SOLVED:

For anyone new to Jinja this solved my issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66598497/13194923
I hope it's helpful