# Addtional rows showing in doc table using jinja

Tags: python, jinja2

I have written a jinja code where I want to add the environment and its servers to the table. Desired output: [image: Desired Output]

Here is my Jinja code in word:

[image: Jinja]

My python code where servers in context include both the environment and the list of attributes, for e.g servers in context, below will be `['Qualif',["Tomcat",7,i," "," "," ",""]]`where i is the server name

```
doc = DocxTemplate("./word_excel_templates/documentation_template.docx")
context = {
    'headers' : ['Component', 'Component Version', 'Server FQDN', 'Application port', 'DB SID', 'DB Port', 'Infos'],
    'servers': []
    }
server_1= ["Tomcat",7,i," "," "," ",""]
#put environment in context as required env
context['servers'].append(environment)
context['servers'].append(server_1)
doc.render(context)        
doc.save("documentation_.docx")
```

Now this is only part of the code, my true servers in context is `['Qualif',["Tomcat",7,i," "," "," ",""], 'Dev',["Tomcat",7,i," "," "," ",""]]`
And the output I am getting is this:

[image: Output I am getting]

I am quite new to Jinja, so I don't know why I am getting these additional cells in the table. Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is actually happening here is that the rows are being drawn as empty if your `row is string` condition equals false. In order to avoid that you could change strategy altogether. I am assuuming that every server is going to have its "environment" label, and if that is the case, firstly, change the format of your word document to:

[image]

Then, adjust your `context` structure as follows:

```py
context = {
'headers' : ['Component', 'Component Version', 'Server FQDN', 'Application port', 'DB SID', 'DB Port', 'Infos'],
'servers':  []
}

server_1 = {}
server_1['environment'] = 'Qualif'
server_1['cols'] = ["Tomcat",7,'a',5000," ",200,""]

server_2 = {}
server_2['environment'] = 'Dev'
server_2['cols'] = ["Tomcat",7,'b',5000," ",200,""]

context['servers'].append(server_1)
context['servers'].append(server_2)
```

This way, the produced output will be:

[image]

If instead you would like to have **multiple** servers into one `environment`, then you should adjust the context to make it have a similar structure:

```py
context = {
'headers' : ['Component', 'Component Version', 'Server FQDN', 'Application port', 'DB SID', 'DB Port', 'Infos'],
'servers':  
         {
           "Qualif": [],
           "Dev" : []
         }
}

server_1 = ["Tomcat",7,'a',5000," ",200,""]
server_2 = ["Tomcat",7,'b',5000," ",200,""]

context['servers']['Qualif'].append(server_1)
context['servers']['Qualif'].append(server_2)
context['servers']['Dev'].append(server_1)
context['servers']['Dev'].append(server_2)
```

And your word file as follows:

[image]

And this is eventually what you will get:

[image]