# Automate Microsoft Excel and Word Using Python: Fill word table from list of names from excel document

Tags: python, excel, automation, ms-word

I am trying to complete the below code for automating form tables in word and excel. It is designed to access an excel table, find the unique names in column 1, then fill out a table in a word document by replacing placeholders ({{placeholder}}) corresponding to the header row text for each row of the excel document.

Currently, it is working, except the replace_placeholders does not recognise the headers, and just replaces the cells in order (column0, column 1, etc).

How would I amend so that it will produce a table of the groupings, but only those column values corresponding to the placeholders

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from docx import Document
from docx2pdf import convert
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog, messagebox, ttk

class DocumentGeneratorApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # Set window properties
        self.title("Document Generator")
        self.geometry("200x400")

        # Style the app
        style = ttk.Style(self)
        style.configure('TButton', font=('Arial', 12), padding=10)
        style.configure('TLabel', font=('Arial', 10), padding=3)

        # Create a frame for better layout
        frame = ttk.Frame(self, padding="10")
        frame.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

        # Add buttons and labels
        ttk.Label(frame, text="Document Generator", font=('Arial', 18)).grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=5)

        ttk.Button(frame, text="Select Excel File", command=self.select_excel_file).grid(row=1, column=0, pady=2, sticky='ew')
        self.excel_label = ttk.Label(frame, text="")
        self.excel_label.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=2, sticky='w')

        ttk.Button(frame, text="Select Word Template", command=self.select_word_template).grid(row=3, column=0, pady=2, sticky='ew')
        self.word_label = ttk.Label(frame, text="")
        self.word_label.grid(row=4, column=0, pady=2, sticky='w')

        ttk.Button(frame, text="Select Output Folder", command=self.select_output_folder).grid(row=5, column=0, pady=2, sticky='ew')
        self.output_label = ttk.Label(frame, text="")
        self.output_label.grid(row=6, column=0, pady=2, sticky='w')

        ttk.Button(frame, text="PDF Conversion", command=self.ask_pdf_conversion).grid(row=7, column=0, pady=2, sticky='ew')
        self.pdf_label = ttk.Label(frame, text="")
        self.pdf_label.grid(row=8, column=0, pady=2, sticky='w')

        ttk.Button(frame, text="Generate Documents", command=self.generate_documents).grid(row=9, column=0, pady=2, sticky='ew')

        # Initialize file paths and flags
        self.excel_file = None
        self.word_template = None
        self.output_folder = None
        self.convert_to_pdf = None

    def select_excel_file(self):
        self.excel_file = filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Select Excel File")
        if self.excel_file:
            self.excel_label.config(text=os.path.basename(self.excel_file))

    def select_word_template(self):
        self.word_template = filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Select Word Template")
        if self.word_template:
            self.word_label.config(text=os.path.basename(self.word_template))

    def select_output_folder(self):
        self.output_folder = filedialog.askdirectory(title="Select Output Folder")
        if self.output_folder:
            self.output_label.config(text=f"Output Folder: {os.path.basename(self.output_folder)}")

    def ask_pdf_conversion(self):
        self.convert_to_pdf = messagebox.askyesno("PDF Conversion", "Would you like to convert the documents to PDF?")
        self.pdf_label.config(text="PDF Conversion: Yes" if self.convert_to_pdf else "PDF Conversion: No")



    def replace_placeholders(self, row_cells, data_row, df):
        for cell, col_name in zip(row_cells, df.columns):
            if col_name in data_row:
                cell.text = str(data_row[col_name])


    def generate_documents(self):
        if not self.excel_file or not self.word_template or not self.output_folder:
            messagebox.showerror("Error", "Please select Excel file, Word template, and Output folder.")
            return

        df = pd.read_excel(self.excel_file)

        # Split comma-separated names and create new rows for each name
        all_rows = []
        for index, row in df.iterrows():
            names = [name.strip() for name in str(row[df.columns[0]]).split(',')]
            for name in names:
                new_row = row.copy()
                new_row[df.columns[0]] = name
                all_rows.append(new_row)
        new_df = pd.DataFrame(all_rows)

        output_dir = os.path.join(self.output_folder, 'output')
        if not os.path.exists(output_dir):
            os.makedirs(output_dir)

        for name, group in new_df.groupby(df.columns[0]):
            doc = Document(self.word_template)

            if doc.tables:
                table = doc.tables[0]
                template_row = table.rows[0].cells  # Copy the first row

                for i, row in enumerate(group.iterrows()):
                    if i == 0:
                        new_row = table.rows[0].cells  # Use the existing first row for the first iteration
                    else:
                        new_row = table.add_row().cells  # Add and use a new row for subsequent iterations
                        for j in range(len(template_row)):
                            new_row[j].text = template_row[j].text  # Copy the text/format from the template row

                    # Replace placeholders in the new row with actual data
                    self.replace_placeholders(new_row, row[1], df)
            else:
                print("No table found in the template document.")

            file_base = str(name)[:25]
            new_doc_filename = os.path.join(output_dir, f'{file_base}.docx')
            doc.save(new_doc_filename)
            print(f"Saved: {new_doc_filename}")

            if self.convert_to_pdf:
                pdf_filename = os.path.join(output_dir, f'{file_base}.pdf')
                convert(new_doc_filename, pdf_filename)
                print(f"Saved: {pdf_filename}")

        messagebox.showinfo("Success", "All documents generated successfully.")

# Create and run the app
app = DocumentGeneratorApp()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Populate word table using python-docx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66589588/populate-word-table-using-python-docx)

Comment: Seems `replace_placeholders` is looping through `row_cells` and `df.columns` in parallel, which doesn't look for _placeholders_ in Word.